# Difference between two Dates, years, months, days, hours, minutes

Tags: javascript, date, time, counter, date-difference

I want to create a counter that shows the difference between two dates. Years, months, days and hours work fine, but the minutes are going to -7 when the actual minutes are at 0.

The starting date is 2020/10/25/1/7 (y/m/d/h/M) and the other date is the actual time.

```js
const beginning = new Date(2020, 9, 25, 1, 7);
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
  window.setInterval(function() {
    console.log(dateDiff(beginning, new Date()));
  }, 1000)
});

function dateDiff(startingDate, endingDate) {
  var startDate = new Date(new Date(startingDate).toISOString().substr(0, 10));
  if (!endingDate) {
    endingDate = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10);
  }
  var endDate = new Date(endingDate);
  if (startDate > endDate) {
    var swap = startDate;
    startDate = endDate;
    endDate = swap;
  }
  var startYear = startDate.getFullYear();
  var february = (startYear % 4 === 0 && startYear % 100 !== 0) || startYear % 400 === 0 ? 29 : 28;
  var daysInMonth = [31, february, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

  var yearDiff = endDate.getFullYear() - startYear;
  var monthDiff = endDate.getMonth() - startDate.getMonth();
  if (monthDiff < 0) {
    yearDiff--;
    monthDiff += 12;
  }
  var dayDiff = endDate.getDate() - startDate.getDate();
  if (dayDiff < 0) {
    if (monthDiff > 0) {
      monthDiff--;
    } else {
      yearDiff--;
      monthDiff = 11;
    }
    dayDiff += daysInMonth[startDate.getMonth()];
  }

  var hourDiff = endingDate.getHours() - startingDate.getHours();
  if (hourDiff < 0) {
    if (dayDiff > 0) {
      dayDiff--;
    } else {
      monthDiff--;
      dayDiff += 1;
    }
  }

  var minuteDiff = endingDate.getMinutes() - startingDate.getMinutes();
  if (minuteDiff < 0) {
    if (hourDiff > 0) {
      hourDiff--;
    } else {
      dayDiff--;
      hourDiff = 23;
    }
  }
  
  return `${yearDiff} y, ${monthDiff} m, ${dayDiff} d, ${hourDiff} h, ${minuteDiff} m`;
}
```

Sorry for the late response, but here is the html code:

```
<!-- COUNTER -->
<center>
    <div>
    <table class="Counterup" >
        <tr style="font-size: 60px; ">
            <td id="years">
                <center>00</center>
            </td>
            <td id="months">
                <center>00</center>
            </td>
            <td id="days">
                <center>00</center>
            </td>
            <td id="hours">
                <center>00</center>
            </td>
            <td id="minutes">
                <center>00</center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <center>&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp; Jahre &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;</center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center>&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp; Monate &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;</center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center>&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp; Tage &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;</center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center>&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp; Stunden &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;</center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center>&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp; Minuten &ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;</center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Adding some HTML to this question would really help, so viewers can paste it into their own systems and debug your code. Right now viewers need to write their own HTML to debug.

Comment: Because when `if (minuteDiff < 0)` you don't adjust *minuteDiff*, you just adjust the *hourDiff*. You should also add 60 to *minuteDiff* (and the same for all the other *\*Diff* variables).